# Blade if() condition error

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to write a if() condition with Blade, I have this :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->username}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td><a href="delmember/{{$user->id}}">Supprimer le membre</a></td>
            @if({{$user->admin}} == 0)
                <td><a href="makeadmin/{{$user->id}}">Passer l'utilisateur Admin</a></td>
            @else
                <td><a href="noadmin/{{$user->id}}">Retirer l'admin à l'utilisateur</a></td>
            @endif
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

I want to check if the user is admin or not (column in my users table) but the if returns me 3 errors :
first one : if(**^here**{{$user->admin}} == 0) -> Expected : condition

Seconde one : if({{$user->admin**^here**}} == 0) -> Expected : semicolon

Third one : if({{$user->admin}}**^here** == 0) -> Expected : Statement

I searched for a while how to fix it but I don't find, maybe someone could help me.

Thank you :)

Comment: `{{` and `}}` is for `echo`ing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside blade tags, you don't need to add another tag. You are currently trying to add `{{ }}` tag inside the `@if()` tag.
Try to think like this: `{{ /* php code */ }}` and `@if(/* php code */)`.

So, to fix your problem, you simply write:

`@if($user->admin == 0)`

and that should be it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
@foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->username}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td><a href="delmember/{{$user->id}}">Supprimer le membre</a></td>
            @if($user->admin == 0)
                <td><a href="makeadmin/{{$user->id}}">Passer l'utilisateur Admin</a></td>
            @else
                <td><a href="noadmin/{{$user->id}}">Retirer l'admin à l'utilisateur</a></td>
            @endif
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

`{{}}` is used to echo. You can directly access variable inside `@if`, like `@if($user->admin == 0)`